# WSDL Parse Error Not able to parse the WSDL Xml

Tags: javascript, ios, xml, parsing, titanium

```
var soapRequest = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:glob="http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global">
 <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <glob:EmployeeLeaveRequestByParticipantQuery>
         <EmployeeLeaveRequestSelectionByParticipant>
            <EmployeeLeaveRequestParticipantRoleCode listVersionID="?">2</EmployeeLeaveRequestParticipantRoleCode>

            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <EmployeeLeaveRequestParticipantWorkAgreementIDInterval>
               <IntervalBoundaryTypeCode>1</IntervalBoundaryTypeCode>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <LowerBoundaryWorkAgreementID schemeID="?" schemeAgencyID="?">1009</LowerBoundaryWorkAgreementID>
        </EmployeeLeaveRequestParticipantWorkAgreementIDInterval>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         </EmployeeLeaveRequestSelectionByParticipant>
      </glob:EmployeeLeaveRequestByParticipantQuery>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>";
```

Did i need to prefix any xml:scheema for my wsdl File or it will parse directly!

How to parse WSDL in JavaScript

@thanks in advance!